# Tablet screen doesn't refresh

Tags: achartengine

I have used AChartEngine for drawing graphs in my App. It works fine on emulator, as in, when I try to remove the graphs through code, it does disappear on emulator but it doesn't disappear on my Tablet or on my phone. The graph doesn't exist, I know that for sure but it is still visible on the screen, the screen doesn't refresh. When I press anywhere on the screen, it is only then that the graph disappears instantly. Could anyone please help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this to the layout that holds your chart.

```
mylayout.removeAllViews();
```

Comment: I have already tried that, it doesn't work. Does it have anything to do with the actual device i-e tablet or cell phone? because the graph does disappear on emulator.

Comment: i am doing the smaething right now and thats waorking on 3 differnt devices plus emulators :)

Comment: Thanks. But it still doesn't work :(. Actually when I touch the graph layout area on the screen, the graph then disappears i-e I have to touch the screen otherwise the graph remains visible.

Comment: I just found the error. The problem wasn't with the code, it was with where I put that code inside the class. I have just fixed it. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do it. How do I close a question?

Comment: You can either post your own answer or select on of the answers provided as correct to close the question :)